# how to equally separate imageviews in a linear layout

Tags: android, layout, view

I have 4 ImageViews that are horizontally placed in a LinearLayout. I need 2 things:

1. If the space is limited by their height, I want them to be distributed equally on the LinearLayout, i.e. with equal spaces between each other
2. If the space is limited by their width, I want the images to shrink so that they will all fit in the view.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `weightSum`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <!-- Put your imageViews here and set android:layout_weight="1" each -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also set minHeight and minWidth

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:minWidth="20dp"
    ></LinearLayout>
```